# Out of space error on SD card even it tells me I have 17GB left

Tags: raspberry-pi, out-of-memory, sd-card

I am testing software on my raspberry pi. It is writing 2kb 10 timers per second to my SD card.

I keep getting out of memory errors and now Rpi will not boot up.

I have mounted this SD card via USB to another Rpi to see the space stats.

This is a screenshot:

[image]

It shows 17Gb available. I have run a disc check on the sd card ands it says it is healthy. I have also Googled and found that it could be the tmp space taken up. But as you can see from the screenshot it is not.

Anyone have any suggestions?

Comment: Are you writing *new files* 10 times a second, without ever deleting old ones?  Linux filesystems have a limit on the number of files (actually, the number of inodes referencing those files) that is set when the filesystem was created; once you reach that limit you cannot create more files, regardless of how much free space is left.

Comment: @jasonharper yes I am. Interesting what you have said.  Do yiou know what that limit is offhand? Thanks for this. Will do some googling!

Comment: @Closer. please explain why you want this closed. I can improve the question if you advise. Thanks

Comment: @jasonharper a quick google check tells me : 4.3 billion inodes.  I may reach 1 couple of million at the very very most

Comment: @jasonharper However, you are correct. Running 'df -hP' tells me IUse is 100%. Thanks very much! please rephrase as an answer and I can accept!